# Time picker inside a loop for

Tags: php, javascript, loops, timepicker

I have form with a loop and I would like to use a time picker. The problem is outside the loop it works fine but inside the loop it doesn't work.
For the 3 input box it's possible to see the time picker but when select the time it will change only the first box.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { ?>
    Time <input type='text' name='timepicker[<?= $i ?>]' class="datepicker_dynamic" id='timepicker[<?= $i ?>]' value=''/>
<?php } ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.datepicker_dynamic').timepicker({
            showLeadingZero: false,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Make this easy on yourself.  Don't output JavaScript with PHP, except for when assigning data.  `echo 'var i = ', json_encode($i), ';'`  (If you're just doing integers, you don't need `json_encode()`.  I just always use it when putting data into JavaScript, as a best-practice.)

Comment: You know, if you do `<?php if [condition] { ?> <!-- Regular HTML/JS code --> <?php } ?>`, it'll still work and look a lot cleaner :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some rearranging to your code:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION["number"]; $i++) { ?>
    Time
    <input type='text' name='timepicker[<?= $i ?>]' id='timepicker_<?= $i ?>' value=''/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#timepicker_<?= $i ?>').timepicker({
                showLeadingZero: false,
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Again, I agree with @Brad that it's probably a good idea not to be generating this much JS unnecessarily, especially when you could do the following with the same results if all the datepickers are identical in functionality:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION["number"]; $i++) { ?>
    Time
    <input type='text' name='timepicker[<?= $i ?>]' class="datepicker_dynamic" id='timepicker[<?= $i ?>]' value=''/>
<?php } ?>
```

And use the following JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.datepicker_dynamic').timepicker({
            showLeadingZero: false,
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:** In the end, the problem ended up being an improper usage of the PHP open tag `<?`. Adding a small explanation here for future reference:

- `<?php  ?>`: The default php open and close tags, always enabled by default
- `<? ?>`: The php short open tag. This may be disabled by default, so check your PHP settings and enable this before using it.
- `<?= ?>`: shorthand for `<?php echo ?>`. Again, might be disabled by default, so check your PHP settings and enable before using.

To enable the short open tags, check your PHP.ini file for short_open_tag

Comment: Thanks, I try it but still have the same problem. it's only work for the first loop. If for example I have 2 input, when I want to do it for the second one it will change the first one already complete. Do i need to put $i in the class also?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with the output of the PHP code? Just hardcode the loop ceiling to something like 3 first so we don't have hundreds of boxes floating around o:

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/godfrzero/2Zzwh/) for you, and it seems to be working fine. Since you haven't posted the output of your PHP code yet I can't help you debug it. Just check if the HTML in the fiddle is similar to your PHP output. While you're at it, check your console for any errors as well.

Comment: sorry i didn't know what a fiddle is. I check what you did and it works but if you do a loop instead of have different number it doesn't work anymore which is my problem

Comment: Again, we'll need to see the HTML output. You can either edit the fiddle I've created, click `Update` at the top and post the link to the update fiddle, or you can update your question with the HTML output that the PHP code generates. This should help everyone understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: I update the fiddle but seems like it doesn't support php http://jsfiddle.net/2Zzwh/2/
so far i didn't find one which support js and php if I find i will put the link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33949/discussion-between-godfrzero-and-user2152947)