# Get Data Javascript To PHP

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker it works well but I would like to get the data after the user submit the form. So far I didn't find the way to do it and I would like to use Post and not Get. I would like to stay in the same page after send it.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ 
    g_globalObject = new JsDatePick({
        useMode:1,
        isStripped:true,
        target:"div3_example"
    });     

    g_globalObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
        var obj = g_globalObject.getSelectedDay();          
        document.getElementById("div3_example_result").innerHTML = obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year;

    }); 
};
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div3_example" style="margin:10px 0 30px 0; border:groove 1px red; width:205px; height:230px;">     
</div>


<div id="div3_example_result" style="height:20px; width:205px; line-height:20px; margin:10px 0 0 0; border:groove 1px #666;"></div>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="button" value="send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: In order to get the data passed, the named fields must first be declared as variables. For example, if you had an input field called **"The Date"**, you would use `<input type="text" name="the_date">` then in your your PHP, you would use `$the_date` as the variable, then `$the_date=$_POST['the_date'];`.

Comment: If you are gathering data about a person, you would use an input field for a first name for instance, inside the form use `<input type="text" name="first_name">` then use `$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];` and `$first_name` being your variable. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I want to get the data the user choose. which so far is inside the JS. "obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year" For now the date is show in the div but I would like to find a way to put it in a php variable

Comment: You could then use `if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // do your stuff }`

Comment: Ok, let me see what I can do.

Comment: the JS is already put. the others one I use is jsDatePick.min.1.3.js

Comment: I saw another question you posted related to your date picker, are you using the same PHP from this >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800524/time-picker-inside-a-loop-for

Comment: So you're not using `<input type='text' name='timepicker` anymore?

Comment: no I decide to change. I put the code I use now

Comment: That's a shame because you could have easily used `timepicker` as your variable.

Comment: You could probably try using `g_globalObject` as your variable, but I doubt it will work.

Comment: And if it does happen to work, you would need to make it as a hidden field while using `name="g_globalObject[]"` so that it's passed as an array. And if that doesn't work, just remove the `[]`.

Comment: The result show is Array

Comment: Ok, well I tried. I don't know what else to say that will help, I'm out of options.